Alexa Skill failing validation due to returning an error using one of the sample phrases - Because the sample phrase causes a slot to be undefined
Using Node.js
Hosting using Lambda
I am having an issue with one of the slots when the user doesn't mention it as part of their interaction.
My intent has a slot called gameMode which may or may not be included as part of the users question so there is a chance that it returns as undefined.
handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.gameMode
Now my code handles the situation where it is undefined
    if (handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.gameMode && handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.gameMode.value) {
        gameMode = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.gameMode.value;
    } else {
        gameMode = "default"; 
    }

When testing this using the Alexa Developer Console this works fine. I get no errors it returns what I expect.
However, when i run it through the validation it fails due to the sample phrase returning an error.
When I check the cloudwatch logs after the validation I can see it has failed on a type error
INFO   ~~~~ Error handled: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'gameMode')
at the line:
if (handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.gameMode && handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.gameMode.value)
of the code I posted above.
Has anyone had experience with this? What is the best way to handle undefined slots?

Yes, the pre-certification tests include a test where there is no slot object supplied, even an empty one.  In practice you always get an empty slot object if no slot is filled but presumably you can't depend upon this remaining to be the case.
So just extend your slot test as follows:
const {slots} = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent;

if (slots && slots.gameMode && slots.gameMode.value) {
        gameMode = slots.gameMode.value;
} else {
        gameMode = "default"; 
}

Refactored slightly to reduce code.
